# Detect SD Card insertion from a Windows service?

Tags: c++, windows, service, sd-card

I need to detect removable media insertion from a Windows service. Using an invisible window, I can successfully detect USB thumbdrives with `RegisterDeviceNotification`, but SD cards are proving more difficult. I've found code that uses `SHChangeNotifyRegister`, but upon further investigation, I've only been able to get it working from a window application.

(Code found from codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3946/Trapping-windows-messages?msg=2897423#xx2897423xx )

```
namespace globals{
    SHChangeNotifyEntry shcne[1];
}
...

globals::shcne[0].pidl = NULL;
globals::shcne[0].fRecursive = TRUE;

globals::hNotify = SHChangeNotifyRegister(globals::hwnd, SHCNE_DISKEVENTS, 
                                          SHCNE_MEDIAINSERTED | SHCNE_MEDIAREMOVED,      
                                          WM_MEDIA_CHANGE, 1, globals::shcne);
```

The error I receive is

> 122 (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER - "The data area passed to a system
>   call is too small.")

This error does not occur in my Win32, window application test program, despite the calls being identical.

Edit: I have resolved the error message (sort of) by registering the service with the `SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS` flag, but I am still not receiving messages in my WndProc.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: My understanding is that these events originate from the shell, which does not exist in session 0.  You either have to do it the hard way via RegisterDeviceNotification or your detection code has to run in the user context.

Comment: The hard way, eh? Well, that's still a positive because it means that this is possible. I was beginning to worry it wasn't. Hard or easy, I don't mind writing a few hundred lines to do this if need be. Could you (or anyone) point me towards any code/guidance that use RegisterDeviceNotification for sd-cards? Everything I find for the function is for USB thumbdrives.

Comment: I found some code I played around with a while ago.  What I was doing was registering for DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE for GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK and GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME.  When I got a notification for either type of device, I would open it with CreateFile() and register for DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE notifications.  These are what give you GUID_IO_MEDIA_ARRIVAL / GUID_IO_MEDIA_REMOVAL notifications.

Comment: @Luke : Doesn't seem to be working for me. I even tried the GUID for hidden volumes out of desperation. I'll make another question for sd-cards using RegisterDeviceNotification since you pretty much answered this one, telling me using SHChangeNotifyRegister was impossible. I'm probably calling something in error.

Comment: If I recall correctly this code worked with a USB multi-card (including SD) reader; what type of SD card reader are you using?  If it's external, try unplugging it, running the code, then plugging it back in.  This code only gets notifications for new devices; for existing devices you will have to open them and register for DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE.

Comment: @Luke : The cardreader is internal. Ideally, my program needs to work for both external USB and internal card readers. But I don't think I'm understanding you... I need to open a handle to any non-existing letter, assign the handle to my DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE struct, and then use RegisterDeviceNotification?

Comment: On startup you can enumerate all disk/volume devices, open them, and register DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE for them; this will handle devices already attached to the system.  Then you can register DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE for GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK and GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME; this will handle devices not already attached to the system.  When you get one of these notifications, you can open the device and register DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE for it as you did in the startup code.  You need to close the device handles and unregister the notifications when you get a device removal notification.

Comment: @Luke Thank you, I think I got it now. SD card messages are arriving. Man, this is tedious! Unfortunately, I'm no longer receiving Volume messages for thumbdrives, but so it goes.

Comment: Nevermind, I missed them pressing Run. Everything is working great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Even if im resurrecting old threads here :

simply use `RegisterDeviceNotification` with `DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE`, you will (of course) have to have your [ControlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241(v=vs.85).aspx) registered via [RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685058(v=vs.85).aspx), in which you need your serviceName - and dont forget that this handle needs to be registered BEFORE you start your Service (also mentioned @ MSDN). You can safely cast your function-pointer to `LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX`, these casts usually are safe as long as your function-signature matches the MSDN-example.

Finally, you are now able to use `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_SMARTCARD_READER` as parameter to `RegisterDeviceNotification`

Your callback has to have this signature : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241(v=vs.85).aspx